# CSS: transition + scale in non-absolute elements

Tags: css, transform, transition

I have a problem in this website:
http://www.bacubacu.com/paybus/

if you hover any of those 3 big round buttons at the bottom the animations works just great (they are absolute).

if you hover where it says "ver historial" the animation jumps to te beginning and stops, even if the "tap" class is still active. I've found out that it is related to the element positioning (being non-absolute).

I have no idea why this is happening, any of you can help me to solve it?

this is the CSS code:

```css
.touch{
    transition: transform 0.15s ease-out;
    -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform 0.15s ease-out;
} 
.touch.tap{
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer myself. it gets fixed when adding "display:inline-block" to the anchor element. I didn't know where the problem was, sorry if my question was not too specific (my english doesn't help either hehe).

https://jsfiddle.net/15ryknk5/10/

```
display:inline-block;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean click instead of hovering. To hover is to place the cursor over the element. That is a different event than clicking. Also I think your css is wrong. I don't know if you can pass transform as a parameter of a transition. FInally I saw you Jquery and it seems to run on click. Try this code

HTML

```
<div id="tap_buttom" class="touch">
    <p>This is a button</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```
    .touch{
            border-radius: 10px;
            background: #ececec;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 150px;
            text-align: center;



            -webkit-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
            -moz-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
            -o-transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
            transition: 0.1s ease-in-out;
            /* Line added by Alvaro Prieto */
            display: inline-block
    } 

.touch.tap
{
        -webkit-transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
        -moz-transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
        -o-transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
        -ms-transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
        transform: scale3D(0.9,0.9,0.9);
 }
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(this).mousedown(function(){
        $("#tap_buttom").addClass("tap")
    })// end click function
    $(this).mouseup(function(){
        $("#tap_buttom").removeClass("tap")
    })// end click function

})// end document.ready
```

You can run this code here https://fiddle.jshell.net/15ryknk5/. I hope this works

Comment: Thank you, it was intended to work on mobile, using mousedown doesn't help for that purpose. However, your script+css has the same problem as you can see in this example: https://jsfiddle.net/15ryknk5/4/     can you please help me to solve it? is it related to the anchor element types?

Comment: ohhhh this was for mobile......did not get that. Also I did not know about the anchors. Your question says non-absolute position elements... let me take a look

Comment: I really appreciate your help, finally I found out that it gets solved when adding "display:inline-block", Im not sure why but it works. Thank you for your time :-)

Comment: awesome... congrats... i'll update my code so people can use this answer later